# Virtual machine (running on Ubuntu Server 20.04) disk space rezise

Tags: server, partitioning, vmware, virtualhost

I want to know if I create a VM from my VMWare vSphere with 500GB disk space. Then I install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on it. In future, will it impact or cause my Ubuntu fail to boot if I reduce the disk space size to 300GB or increase it to 600GB? I know in Windows OS I can easily expand the disk space, it won't impact my VM but not sure about Ubuntu OS.

At the moment, I testing it on Oracle VirtualBox. If I expand the disk space or reduce it, it cause my Ubuntu not bootable.

Comment: Please clarify product/release details; as there was no Ubuntu Server release in 2020-February (20.02) so you've either made errors in the question, or you've not got a legitimate Ubuntu product.  Providing details about the type of install, or file-system may also help, as changing partition size can be easy/difficult depending on a few factors you've not specified.